# API BIM350: Too Many Requests: Quota limit exceeded

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We trying using API BIM360

Often We can get the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests. {"developerMessage":"Quota limit exceeded."}}

Are there any recommendations for using the API to prevent such an error?

Thanks

Comment: Which API did you play with? It seems you're calling Forge Data Management API for BIM360, didn't you? There is a rate limit per Client Id, see here for detail: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/rate-limiting/

Comment: @EasonKang
Thanks for your reply!
Yes. It happens in Data Management API
but in the BIM 360 API, this is also happening.

Comment: I would like to double check with you if the BIM360 API you mentioned is BIM 360 API [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/), its old name is BIM360 HQ API?

Comment: @EasonKang
Yes. I used BIM360 API here [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/)

Comment: Thank you for confirming, I'm checking with our engineering team. In the same time, could you share which BIM360 API did you called that shows this message?

Comment: According to our engineering team, all Forge APIs are rate limited. So, could you share how you play with our APIs to me? Let's see what happened!

Comment: @EasonKang
we used API requests [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-import-POST/).



users count > 300. so this request is sent > 4 times.



get the response:


"The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests. {"developerMessage":"Quota limit exceeded."}}"


or


"{"fault":{"faultstring":"Gateway Timeout","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.GatewayTimeout"}}}".

may need to put a timeout? If so, tell me which one so that it is efficient and free from errors.

Comment: If it’s required only 4 times API calls to complete the user import procedures, you should not receive the rate limit warning. Could you consider providing a none confidential reproducible test code example demonstrating this issue? If it’s not allowed to be posted here, please sent it to forge.help[AT]autodesk dot com

Comment: @EasonKang
<p> We used BIM360 API requests adds users to project [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/) </p>
> [code example](https://yadi.sk/i/FOMX07mJZeybyg).
> We send many requests, it is true. we are ready to wait between requests.
> What timeout do i need to put between requests so that this never happens "The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests. {"developerMessage":"Quota limit exceeded."}}"?

Comment: I looked into your code, but it should not be a problem. However, I would advise you to use something like [awiat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) to wait for returning result of the previous API call, and then execute the next one.

Comment: Furthermore, please check if there are any other API calls to Forge service using the same Client Id in the same time. As I know, the rate limit is counting on the connection per second of one Client Id, not your app itself.

Comment: @EasonKang
We have already cancel asynchronous methods due to this error. all methods are to wait for returning result of the previous metodth (API call), and then executed the next one.
We still get the error "(429) Too many requests."
what timeout need to be set between requests? What is the limit of requests per second for Client Id?

Comment: It's something like this https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/develop/rate-limiting, I would advise you to provide a none-confidential, tiny and runnable reproducible app demonstrating this issue to `forge.help [AT] autodesk [DOT] com`. **Please remove any personal info., company data, and secret from anything you want to provide to us**.